# regular expression to match an odd number in a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match only odd numbers in a string. What I'm thinking is to detect whether the last digit of the number is odd or not, but now I can only find the first (n-1) digits except for the last one.

For example, the following code works for the odd number `13`, which is perfect! But when it turns to `132`, the code still returns 13, which definitely fails. So, how can I manipulate the code and let it work for all numbers (no matter how large it is) ending with odd digits? Thank you!

```
match= '(\s*\d*[13579]\s*)'
print(re.search(match, "The number 13 matches")) #<re.Match object; span=(10, 14), match=' 13 '>
print(re.search(match, "The number 132 matches")) #<re.Match object; span=(10, 13), match=' 13'>
```

Comment: Add terminators:  https://regex101.com/r/oxoYVL/1

Comment: This is pretty cool!

Answer (score 2):

You can match

```
\d+(?!\d)(?<=[13579])

23 132 87 74 101
^^     ^^    ^^^
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/nExpEV/1)

```
\d+      # match one or more digits
(?!      # begin negative lookahead
  \d     # match a digit
)        # end negative lookahead
(?<=     # begin positive lookbehind
[13579]  # match an odd digit
)        # end positive lookbehind
```

`(?!\d)` could be replaced by `(?=\D|$)`, a positive lookahead that asserts that the match is followed by a non-digit or is at the end of the string.

Comment: I see from @Ryszard's answer that I should have written `\d*[13579](?!\d)`. What was I thinking?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regex, `\d+[13579](?=\s|$)` which can be explained as

- `\d+` : One or more digits
- `[13579]` : 1, 3, 5, 7, or 9
- `(?=\s|$)` : Positive lookahead assertion for whitespace or end of line

**Demo:**

```
import re
match= '\d+[13579](?=\s|$)'
print(re.search(match, "The number 13 matches")) 
print(re.search(match, "The number 132 matches"))
```

**Output:**

```
<re.Match object; span=(11, 13), match='13'>
None
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```py
(?<!\d)\d*[13579](?!\d)
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/n4G5jk/1/).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<!                     look behind to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \d*                      digits (0-9) (0 or more times (matching
                           the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [13579]                  any character of: '1', '3', '5', '7', '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?!                      look ahead to see if there is not:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d                       digits (0-9)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
```

**[Python code](https://tio.run/##NYzBCsIwEETv@Yo1p0SkUIqoRekfePJmRWq7Njk0CZst6NfHVto5zTDzJnzZeFccA6Vkh@CJgVAQ9viBC5BU1XlTd7rutve82B9OD1XNWQrGyM/INK3kzSC4cXghQV7A0HBrMEqxmPkHs4gNtUb9n3ew0lrY9wqAjeA8w9U7LAVMCmQdq6XOevJjUFqn9AM)**:

```py
import re
regex = r"(?<!\d)\d*[13579](?!\d)"
test_str = "The number 13 matches"
matches = re.search(regex, test_str)
if matches is not None:
    print(matches.group())
```

**Results**: `13`.

**Also** word boundaries could be used:

```py
\b\d*[13579]\b
```

Comment: I see no reason for the negative lookbehind. Without it your answer is clearly preferable to mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a non-greedy search of decimals `\d*?` followed by an odd number `[13579]` and a word boundary `\b`. Put it together

```
import re

tests = [("The number 13 matches", True), 
    ("The number 132 matches", False)]

for test, is_match in tests:
    match = re.search(r"\d*?[13579]\b", test)
    print(repr(test), bool(match), "PASS" if bool(match) == is_match else "FAIL")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a look ahead to check that the odd digit is not followed by another digit:

```
match = '\d*[13579](?!\d)'
```